# Maximum edge of a directed graph , if it contains weak components?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

A digraph includes n nodes , and has two weak components , what is the maximum number of edges? ( there is no directed cycle)?

Another question ,how does the answer change , if there is two strong components instead of weak components in the digraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious that the maximum number of edges for a directed graph of two weak components is twice of the maximum number of edges for an undirected graph of two connected components. The latter is $\binom {n} {2} - (n-1)$, since the maximum number of edges for an undirected graph of two connected components is attained by partitioning $n$ vertices into two parts. More precisely, it is a disjoint union of complete graphs $K_r$, $K_{n-r}$ for some integer $0<r<n$, and the maximum number of edges is attained when $r=1$ or $n-1$. Hence, the answer is $2\left(\binom {n} {2} - (n-1)\right)=2\binom{n-1}{2}$.

Similarly, if we consider a directed graph $G$ with two strong components, again, let $V_1, V_2$ be a partition of the vertex set of $G$ such that $G[V_1]$ and $G[V_2]$ are the two strong components of $G$. Then, without loss  of generality, we can assume there is no edge from $V_1$ to $V_2$, thus $G$ has at most $2\binom{n}{2}-|V_1||V_2|$ edges. To maximize it, note that $|V_1||V_2|\geq n-1$ and obviously there is such required directed graph with $2\binom{n}{2}-(n-1)=(n-1)^2$ edges, and that is the answer.

Comment: So  we can say that - if we have 10 nodes and two strong components in a graph , the minumum number of edges is 11 , and maximum (10−1)2  = 81 edges ?

Comment: No, if we have 10 nodes and the directed graph has two strong components, then it can 9 edges for the minimum, for instance, a directed circuit and a isolated vertex. For the maximum, yes, 81.

Comment: Thank you , as the last question , if we consider that each two strong components has 2 nodes at least. How does the min and max numbers change?

Comment: So I assume the graph $G$ has at least $4$ vertices, the minimum $n$ is attained by $C_2+C_{n-2}$, the maximum $2\left(\binom{2}{2}+\binom{n-2}{2}\right)+2(n-2)$ is attained by the graph $K_2+K_{n-2}+\frac{1}{2}K_{2,n-2}$.

Comment: But we  still know that we have 10 nodes.

Comment: min 10, max 74.